# Getting "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'"

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Hi I know there are a few people that had this issue but none of the solutions I've seen are helping. I'm taking a set of data, reading the file then creating arrays from the data to input into this equation:
`Dist = 10 ** ((app_m - abs_M + 5.) /5)`
Where I app_m and abs_M are the arrays from the data.

I'm using Python 2.7 and only just learning so if things can be explained as simply as possible that would be great

Comment: Lists cannot be subtracted, do it another way. What's the desired output? You want `[4, 3] - [2, 1]` to result into `[2, 2]`, or...? And how do you expect to append `5` to those lists?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this with

```
 Dist = []
for i in range(len(app_m)):
    Dist.append((float(app_m[i]) - float(abs_M[i]) + 5.)/5)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not use `list` - `list`

you can just change your code like this

```
import numpy as np
Dist = 10 ** ((np.array(app_m) - np.array(abs_M) + 5.) /5)
```